# how to override product grid listing magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, grid

I have added the sequence Magento catalog to my module. I also copied the content of grid_listing, but i can't see the override working. Where i am wrong please.

Comment: list.phtml is responsible for both `list` and `grid view`.

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite the listing template, make sure you have the exact following structure and file name: `app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`.

You shouldn't need to specify the sequence manually as this will take priority over the default Magento template file.

Comment: do you mean that list.phtml will change the grid of product listing ...??

Comment: If you look at the top of the file, you'll see an if statement that assigns your `$viewMode` to either `grid` or `list`, your product listing/grid gets built by that template file.

Comment: I want to override the ui component and not Frontend

Answer (score 0):

Try overide theme:

> yourVendor\yourTheme\Magento_CatalogWidget\templates\product\widget\content\grid.phtml

Comment: i mean by grid the grid listing of product in BO and not Frontend